# Как проверить на корректность возвращаемый список значений из БД со списком из веб-страницы?

Tags: python, тестирование, pytest

Проверка требуется для проекта автотестирования на `pytest+selenium`. Вот код:

```
 def should_be_correct_list_branches(self):
     assert self.is_element_present(*BasePageLocators.FILIAL_LIST_2), "The list of branches is not available"
     branch_1 = self.browser.find_element(*ResponseDocumentsPageLocators.LIST_BRANCHES_1)
     assert branch_1.text.split(' ', maxsplit=1)[1] == self.get_list_of_branches(), "The list of branches is incorrect"
     all_branch = self.browser.find_elements(*ResponseDocumentsPageLocators.LIST_BRANCHES)
     for span in all_branch:
         assert span.text.split(' ', maxsplit=1)[1] == self.get_list_of_branches(), "The list of branches is incorrect"
```

Проверка в первом `assert` проходит успешно, т.к. на веб-странице находится 1 значение через `find_element` и ему сопоставляется 1 значение из запроса из БД `self.get_list_of_branches()`.
Второй `assert` выдает ошибку `AssertionError`. С помощью `find_elements` находится некий список значений и сопоставляется с тем, что находит запрос из БД. Подскажите, как корректно выполнить эту проверку?

Comment: А метка [oracle] здесь при чём?

Comment: В вопросе идет речь о запросе из БД - как раз из Oracle

Comment: Хорошо. А какие проблемы с запросом из БД, ошибки, неожидаемый результат?

Comment: С запросом из БД проблем нет, он отрабатывает корректно

Comment: Если так, то и метка не нужна, уже удалил.